# Putting the callback on the same line

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am not a Ruby developer by any means and am modifying a Chef recipe. I'm curious if it is possible to put the following into one line.

```
directory "/var/lib/mysql" do
  action :delete
end
```

I tried this:

```
directory "/var/lib/mysql", :action => "delete"
```

However, that throws this error:

```
ArgumentError
-------------
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
```

I've seen this as well, but this just seems awkward to me:

```
directory "/var/lib/mysql" do action => "delete" end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Braces are equivalent to `do...end`, and are much more commonly used for one-liners:

```
directory("/var/lib/mysql") { action :delete }
```

Adding the parentheses is required to avoid ambiguity, since braces are also used to define hashes.

Comment: Now what if the call has two args. `directory "/var/lib/mysql/data" do owner "mysql" group "mysql" end`. Converting that to `directory("/var/lib/mysql/data") { owner "mysql" group "mysql" }` results in a compilation error.

Comment: What you refer to as "args" are actually method calls -- they are lines of Ruby code. You are calling the method `owner` with the argument `"mysql"`, and then the method `group` with the argument `"mysql"`. You need to indicate these are separate lines (and not just one long string of arguments to the `owner` method) by placing semicolons in between: `{ owner "mysql"; group "mysql" }`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do two ways, as said using something called a `block`

```
directory("/var/lib/mysql") { action :delete }
```

and you can put your code this way, just to tell you the semi-colon exists in ruby ;))

```
directory "/var/lib/mysql" do ; action :delete ; end
```